# validate form field for null or empty using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am using the following javascript code to check for nothing being entered in a form and it is not working. Can anyone suggest a reason?

```
           function validateForm()
{
    var a=document.getElementById("quiz_01").value;
    $question = a;
    if (a=="" || a==null) {
      alert("Question 201 must be filled out");
      form1.quiz_01.focus();
      return false;
      }
}
```

An extract of the html is as follows:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action=""  onsubmit="return validateForm()">
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="quiz_01">201 A one followed by 100 zeros is a Googol</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select name="quiz_01" id="quiz_01">
                <option value=" "> </option>
                <option value="100">100</option>
                <option value="90">90</option>
                <option value="80">80</option>
                <option value="70">70</option>
                <option value="60">60</option>
                <option value="50">50</option>
                <option value="40">40</option>
                <option value="30">30</option>
                <option value="20">20</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="0">0</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<p>
    <input type="submit" name="next" value="Next &gt;">
</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first option:

```
<option value=" "> </option>
```

Has a value that is a single space, not an empty string. So either change the `value` or change the JS code. Note also that the `.value` property will never be `null` so you don't need to test for that.

```
if (a == " ") {
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RyN5W/

Comment: Thanks very much. I changed to "<option value=""> </option>"  and "if (a == " ") {" and that worked. The comments of subhash and mohkahn were also relevant, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Trim the whitespaces.

```
 var a=document.getElementById("quiz_01").value.trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
if (a=="" || a==null)
```

to

```
if (a==" " || a==null)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be checking for " " as per your HTML

```
if (a == " ") {
```

Answer (score 0):

change the code to

```
var e = document.getElementById("quiz_01");
    var ev = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

if(ev===' '){
alert('question 201 is a required field');

}
```

you should use === not == whwn comparing strings

Answer (score 0):

You could not access the value directly when working with an *<select>* element.
use following:

```
var element = document.getElementById("quiz_01");
var a = element.options[element.selecedIndex];
```

***EDIT:*** (credits to [nnnnnn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/615754/nnnnnn)) 
In modern browsers the direct access will work, but if you're targeting an old Version (I think especially of Internet Explorer ;) ) the showed approach will gain you compatibility.

Comment: That was true in certain old browsers (except you want `element.selectedIndex` not `element.selecedValue`), but I think you'll find every modern browser lets you use `.value` directly on the select element to get the selected item.